# NOT NULL contraint failed: campgrounds_campground.author_id

Tags: python, django

First go at building a Django app solo.

I've set up a user model as follows

```
class User(auth.models.User):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Everything works fine there. I've then created a campground model

```
class Campground(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User' , related_name='submitted_campgrounds')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, unique=True)
    image = models.URLField(blank=False)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('campgrounds:single', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Edit

View Code

```
class CreateCampground(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'image', 'description')
    model = Campground
```

Form is coming from the CreateView.

I'm getting the error when submitting a form to create a new campground.

Shound't it be taking the user id from the logged in user? I do have the LoginRequiredMixin on the view for the create view.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please add the code for the view where you are adding the `Campground`.

Comment: show your form and data

Comment: Please add the error

Comment: Edited. Error is in title

Answer (score 0):

Your code seams to be fine. There might be an issue with existing user who does not have an object Campground as you just created new model Campground. I remember to fix this issue by logging to Django's admin, and manually create a Campground for any user who hasn't got Campground. Alternatively, you can try to delete that user, and makemigrations again.

Hope this help.

Cheers
Henry

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this to my CreateCampground view

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super(CreateCampground, self).form_valid(form)
```